# Keyboard not detected when trying to install Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.10

I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition on my laptop and unfortunately it didn't detect my keyboard (it detects my mouse) so I couldn't finish installation.

Is it something wrong I'm doing? There isn't really much to specify during the installation process and I'm really disappointed that such a trivial task as installation cannot be done without asking a question on a forum.

Maybe it's because I'm trying to install it on my laptop? Shall I the download the notebook edition? That sound silly to me.

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little bit more about your configuration so that we could help better

Comment: bubu, well, Hewlett Packard Pavilion dv9000, nvidia as a graphic card, intel centrino duo, 160GB hard drive, 2GB memory. This laptop is 4 years old now.

Comment: Do you know how your keyboard is detected in other operating systems? Does ti work with other distributions? Does it work with other distributions using same kernel version?

Comment: It's very unlikely the Netbook edition would be any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During this part of the install could you type in the box where you see "hello Ubuntu" ?

.

[image]

Comment: I've just discovered that whenever I switch on of my pad on my laptop the whole keyboard isn't working and system restart is needed. So far definitely not impressed by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting some of the boot options as shown on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions). My older laptop also had problems with keyboard detection. I believe that the option acpi=off or noapci fixed it. Another tool is the on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[Netbook](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download) edition works.. But I have installed ubuntu10.10 on my sis's laptop and it worked fine...